# tableView display "no results" issue with delete row

Tags: xcode, tableview

I put message "no results" when my tableview is empty.
the problem is that when I have 1 row and I want to delete this row number of rows 
don't change because I have if condition that show me "no results" use row,
I can make bool property that check if deleted and then if user delete this row that will not show him message "no results", but maybe someone have better way?

my methods:

num of sections:

```
if([[[self fetchResultsController] fetchedObjects] count] == 0)
        return 1;
```

rows in section:

```
if([[[self fetchResultsController] fetchedObjects] count] == 0)
        return 1;
```

cell:

```
if([[[self fetchResultsController] fetchedObjects] count] == 0){

        [[cell textLabel] setText:@"no results"];

    }else{ //create regular or from search cell.
```

Comment: when you delete the row remove the object from the array and reload the table

Comment: That what I do, the problem is that after it I have row with title "no result" (I want this row). so the app crush because I didn't change number of rows :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution that I find is make a title instead of cell to avoid problems with delete and update (core data). but title as I know can't appear if there no rows or sections. So I solute it with this two methods:

```
-(void) hideTitle{
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
}

-(void) showTitle{

    self.contener = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 40)];
    self.label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];

    self.label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Header for the table", @"");
    self.label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    self.label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22];
    self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.contener addSubview:[self label]];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.contener; 
}
```

I put this one named show at the **num_of_sections..**:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if([[[self fetchResultsController] fetchedObjects] count] == 0)
        [self showTitle];  .....}
```

this method works well when delete rows.
the second method named hide I use when I create new row (I put the method in my "save method") this method delete the title.

edit:
**another way:**

As I try before num of row...

```
if([[bla bla] count] == 0 && is_deleted == 0)
        return 1;
```

change cell too:

```
if([[bla bla] count] == 0){

    [[cell textLabel]setText:@"no results"];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:nil];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

}else{ 

  cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

 ... }
```

the issue id a delete row so I use bool to avoid crush at `didLoad method bool = 0;`
when I `delete I insert 1 to the bool` don't forget cancel the delete option for this cell!!

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete && [[bla bla] count] != 0)
        { ... }
```

the problem with this solution that it's not perfect, when I delete the last row my tableView is empty only when I load table again the title appear that not what I want.

***If someone have more elegant solution please tell me I promise check your answer as correct answer.***

Comment: maybe I should use [view setNeedDisplay] but I don't know how and where.

Answer (score 0):

Write Following for **numberOfSectionsInTableView**

```
if([[[self fetchResultsController] fetchedObjects] count] == 0)
        return 1;
else
        return [[[self fetchResultsController] fetchedObjects] count];
```

When you are deleting the value remove the object from array and reload the table.
Let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: there still problems with objectAtIndex that get 0.
you can try run it in my project 
https://github.com/dennis87/eventCost
the problem is with my first table view.